# stalked and downvoted by upset users?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

I noticed my reputation activity over the last 24 hrs, and it looks as though some user has followed every question on my profile and targeted it for downvote. This behavior is hilarious, but the down-votes seem more like a personal attack than a reflection on the quality of the questions, which may take away from the intent of the voting system.  Should such behavior be tolerated @ Programmers and if not, how would you address this?

Comment: We'll check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user has been contacted privately. The system should resolve the downvotes within the next few days.

Comment: thanks for looking into this.